# Nodejs: extends class and change parent variable per child classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This is my classes:

```
export class Parent {
  protected static name: string;

  public getName() {
    return Parent.name
  }
}

export class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (!Child1.name) {
      // connect to database for get names
      Child1.name = '1';
    }
  }
}

export class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (!Child2.name) {
      // connect to database for get names
      Child2.name = '2';
    }
  }
}
```

I run this code:

```
let child1 = new Child1()
let child2 = new Child2()

console.log(child1.getName())
console.log(child2.getName())
```

And I get this result:

```
undefined
undefined
```

But I get this result:

```
1
2
```

I want to connect to database and get `names`, so per `new class` I dont want to connect to database again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parent.name` will always access the `name` property of `Parent`. If you want to make it conditional on which instance the function is called on you have to use `this.constructor.name` instead:

```
public getName() {
  return this.constructor.name
}
```

`this.constructor` refers to the object's constructor function / class.

```js
class Parent {

  getName() {
    return this.constructor.db
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (!Child1.db) {
      // connect to database for get names
      Child1.db = '1';
    }
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (!Child2.db) {
      // connect to database for get names
      Child2.db = '2';
    }
  }
}

let child1 = new Child1()
let child2 = new Child2()

console.log(child1.getName())
console.log(child2.getName())
```

Comment: Can you add some codes like my codes? because I can't access with this.constructor to static variables.

Comment: I added an  example.

Comment: The result is wrong => `Child1 Child2`. But I want to get `1 2`.

Comment: Ah good catch. Use a different property name then. Functions/classes already have a built-in `name` property. I updated the example.

Comment: Thank you. But I get this error: `Property 'db' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

Comment: You might have to typecast `this.constructor` to a more appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is static members are bound to the class and can not be referenced via an instance.

Use it like this:

```
class Parent {
  protected static name: string;

  public getName() {
    return Parent.name
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (!Parent.name) {
      Parent.name = '1';
    }
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (!Parent.name) {
      // connect to database for get names
      Parent.name = '2';
    }
  }
}

let child1 = new Child1();
let child2 = new Child2();

console.log(child1.getName());
console.log(child2.getName());
```

Comment: Your code does not work fine. because the result is: `11`. in `Child2`, `Parent.name` is not `null`. So, `Parent.name = '2';` not called.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Parent {
    protected namE: string;

    public getName() {
        return this.namE
    }
    
}

export class Child1 extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super()
        if (!this.namE) {
            // connect to database for get namEs
            this.namE = '1';
        }
    }
}

export class Child2 extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super()
        if (!this.namE) {
            // connect to database for get namEs
            this.namE = '2';
        }
    }
}




    let child1 = new Child1()
    let child2 = new Child2()

    console.log(child1.getName())
    console.log(child2.getName())
```

OutPut:

```
1
2
```

Why don't you do it this way?

Comment: Because for any `new child`, I have to connect to database. I want just once connect to database